# CRUD, after click Save in Add or Edit

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, atk4

/var/www/page/page/video.php:

```
<?php
class page_video extends Page {
    function init(){`enter code here`
        parent::init();

        $form=$this->add('Form');

        $d=$this->add('Tabs');
        $d->addTab('klienci_w')->add('CRUD')->setModel('KlienciW');

        if($form->isSubmitted()){
            $form->js()->execute();
       }

    }  

    }
```

/var/www/page/lib/Model/KlienciW.php

```
<?php
class Model_KlienciW extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code='klienci_w';
    public $debug=true;

        function init(){
                parent::init();


    $this->addField('adresid');
    $this->addField('adresn');
    $this->addField('adresu');
    $this->addField('adresk');
    $this->addField('adresp');
    $this->addField('aosoba');
    $this->addField('aosobat');
    $this->addField('odbiorcaid');
    $this->addField('data')->type('date');
    $this->addField('datau')->type('date');

        }

    }
```

I have an answer form Chrome (in Firefox is the same):

```
insert into `klienci_w` (`adresid`,`adresn`,`adresu`,`adresk`,`adresp`,`aosoba`,`aosobat`,`odbiorcaid`,`data`,`datau`) values ("sdfsd","fsdf","sdfsd","fsdf","sdfsd","fsdfsd","fsdf","sdf","2012-05-16","2012-05-18") [:a_10, :a_9, :a_8, :a_7, :a_6, :a_5, :a_4, :a_3, :a_2, :a]
select `id`,`adresid`,`adresn`,`adresu`,`adresk`,`adresp`,`aosoba`,`aosobat`,`odbiorcaid`,`data`,`datau` from `klienci_w` where `id` = "6" limit 0, 1 [:a]
$('#Frontend_video_tabs_view_htmlelement_crud').trigger('reload');$('#Frontend_video_tabs_view_htmlelement_crud_form').univ().closeDialog()
```

In MySQL this data was added to the DB, but the Form is still on primary screen in web browser, on PostgreSQL nothing happend, but the Form is still on primary screen in web browser.

ATK4 in version 4.2 and 4.2.1.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turn debug off by removing debug=true line.